# Select part of an image

Tags: javascript, image, select

I want to identify things in an image by 'drawing' a rectangle round them.
E.g. to select a face in a crowd. A sign in a street etc.

How to use the mouse events to
a) mousedown to start select area
Grow a 'rectangle' to follow the mouse movements.
b) mouseup to end selection.
Retrieve the xy, xy of the box for use in further processing.
I'd like x and y values of the rectangle to be relative to the img element with id value 'image' if that's possible please.